# Calling C++ libraries from Python or Java using Eclipse

Tags: java, c++, python, eclipse

I am trying to call a library written in C++ called VFML (http://www.cs.washington.edu/dm/vfml/) in Python or Java using Eclipse. I am new to Python and have not programmed in C language. Is there any methods to do this that doesn't require the knowledge of C++ programming as it would take time to learn the language. Any tutorials or guides on how this can be done would help as well.

I use Eclipse to run both Python modules and Java classes. It would be great if anyone knows if it's possible to call the C++ library in Eclipse using Java or Python.  Thank you.

Edit 1:

Thanks for all the answers. I was mistaken about VFML being written in C++. It was C language as pointed out. It would seems most of the answers given would suggest some kind of understanding of the C language in order to call the libraries in Python or even Java. I have heard of SWIG. Any ideas if this would be workable as without any knowledge in C language I cannot even know if I can get the library working properly. Another question would be if there is any Eclipse plugin for SWIG as I use both Python and Java  with Eclipse.

Comment: You definitely want to use Python over Java... but that would require some C++ programming...

Comment: FYI, that library is written in C, not C++

Comment: @Dikei You can still use C++ to write the interface.  (I would recommend it; RAII helps enormously when managing lifetime issues.)

Comment: I'm using boost to interface C++ with Python code, and I think it's really awesome!! The main reason is because it's very easy to create a C++ object and export it to python, even the stl containers. One con, it needs a good knowledge about C++ and some time to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call directly into C++ either in Python or in Java;
you have to write some bridging code.  Given that the external
interface to Python and in Java is C, this bridging code can be
more or less complicated: strings are char*, with all of the
memory management issues that implies, and reporting errors
generally require calling into the interface level to create an
exception in the targeted language.

The interface code for Python is fairly simple, except for these
issues, but it still requires a fairly good knowledge of C++ in
order to use RAII effectively on the Python objects.  The
interface to Java (JNI) is inordinately complex, and requires
numerous calls back into Java to do even the simplest
operations, as well as all of the usual resource management.

Comment: Thanks for pointing all that out to me. I do not think I would have time to learn up C/C++ at the moment. RAII might not be a good option for me now. What about SWIG? I read that it is supposed to be easy to use.

Comment: Swig is probably a good answer, especially if the library is already written and you don't really know C++.  Given the C++ header files, it will generate all of the interface code for you; you just have to learn enough to be able to compile and link it.

Answer (score 2):

To call c++ dll method using Java you can use Java Native Access library. It's really easy to use. All you need to do is to create interface and you can use it.

For example lets imageine that you have got dll with `GetSystemIp(out char[] ip)`, interface for this method will look like this:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface DllLibrary extends Library {
    DllLibrary INSTANCE = (DllLibrary)
        Native.loadLibrary(dllPath, DllLibrary.class);
    int GetSystemIp(String ip);

}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
String ip;
int rc = DllLibrary.INSTANCE.GetSystemIp(String ip);
```

More info can be found on [jna site](https://github.com/twall/jna) and on [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access).

Comment: Perhaps I should ask if any knowledge of C/C++ language is needed before I can use JNA to bridge the two program?

Comment: All you need to know is dll method prototype and how to connect c++ type to Java type. For example lets imagine that you have got dll with exported method `GetMyWifeName(char* wifeName)`. In java this prototype will look like this `GetMyWifeName(String wifeName)`. Everything you need to know is mapping types which can be found on wikipedia JNA page.